# Name of music in commercial 2 for mermaid scar

Tags: classical-music

What is the name of the musical piece from [commercial # 2 of the anime “mermaids scar”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=ggPqAxjcZxY&app=desktop)?

Comment: Yes. Mermaid Scar, commercial #2. I think it’s Gymnopedie #5.

Comment: Erik Satie-gymnopedie no.1, thanks to those who tried. It’s a great piece.

Comment: you can turn your comment into an answer  and accept your own answer, odd though it seems.....

Comment: Sorry, Gymnopedie #1, Erik Satie. It’s a great piece.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=ggPqAxjcZxY

Comment: Welcome to Musicfans Stackexchange, Tom. I have added the link to your question for you.

Comment: The cello melody only shares four notes with Satie's first Gymnopedie.

Comment: @tom This might be inspired by Gymnopedie #1, but it's NOT the same piece.

Answer (score 1):

As per the original poster, in the comments:

Erik Satie - [Gymnopedie no.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-Xm7s9eGxU)

Comment: You should write it as "Community Wiki" if the answer is taken from someone else in the comments.